# How do I create if then logic in self-join condition?

Tags: postgresql, self-join

I have a data set with Student names, Skills, and their scores in these skills by year.
I want a query to find which student has had the highest growth in any skill? The period for growth can be 1-3 years (there are missing values for some years).

So, if there are records for 2000, 2001 and 2002 for a student and a skill, to calculate growth for 2002, we need to look at 2001.
If there were only records for 2000 and 2002 for a student and a skill, to calculate growth, we can look at 2000 (only if 2001 is not present).

I thought of doing a self join to create a basis to compare scores. Tried to create the growth period logic in this join condition but got stuck.

```
SELECT q1.STUDENT, q1.SKILL, q1.YEAR, q2.YEAR, q1.SCORE, q2.SCORE
FROM Table q1
INNER JOIN Table q2
ON q1.STUDENT = q2.STUDENT AND q1.SKILL = q2.SKILL AND ... 
-- This is where I get stuck

(q1.YEAR = q2.YEAR - 1)  -- Case 1
(q1.YEAR <> q2.YEAR - 1) AND (q1.YEAR = q2.YEAR - 2) -- Case 2
(q1.YEAR <> q2.YEAR - 1) AND (q1.YEAR <> q2.YEAR - 2) AND (q1.YEAR = q2.YEAR - 3) -- Case
```

I understand that these cases are kind of getting unioned right now? How do I make them run in an IF logic manner?

Sample Data:

[image]

**Should they be three different queries unioned together instead?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lag` window function to calculate the growth instead of self join.

```sql
with t as
(
 select 
   student, skill, 
   case when year-lag(year) over w <= 3 then score-lag(score, 1) over w end as growth
 from _table
 window w as (partition by student, skill order by year)
)
select distinct on (skill) student, skill, growth
from t
order by skill, growth desc nulls last;
```

In the `t` CTE `growth` will be `null` for every first year in a (student, skill) group of records.